# How do I add a js map to Pyqt5?

Tags: javascript, python, pyqt5

I want to add the map provided by Marinetraffic to pyqt5. When I add the HTML codes provided by MarineTraffic to my own program, it doesn't work.
The map I want to add:
[MarineTraffic Map JS](https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/p/embed-map)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets, QtWebChannel


class Backend(QtCore.QObject):
    valueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._value = ""

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(str)
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, v):
        self._value = v
        self.valueChanged.emit(v)


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.webEngineView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.webEngineView, stretch=1)
        lay.addWidget(self.label, stretch=1)

        backend = Backend(self)
        backend.valueChanged.connect(self.label.setText)
        backend.valueChanged.connect(self.foo_function)
        self.channel = QtWebChannel.QWebChannel()
        self.channel.registerObject("backend", backend)
        self.webEngineView.page().setWebChannel(self.channel)

        path = "index.html"
        self.webEngineView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(path))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def foo_function(self, value):
        print(value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I run it, I get a connection failed error.
As a result of my searches, I get the same error in all the methods I tried, where am I doing wrong, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation for *QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile* :

[QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtCore/QUrl.html#PySide6.QtCore.PySide6.QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile)

*"A file URL with a relative path only makes sense if there is a base URL to resolve it against."*

So we add the base path:

```
import os
...

        path = os.getcwd() + "\\index.html"
        self.webEngineView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(path))
```

Added path compatibility between os (edited)

```
from pathlib import Path
...
        base_path = Path(Path.cwd())
        full_path = base_path.joinpath('index.html')
        self.webEngineView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(str(full_path)))
```

Comment: That might not comply with other systems: remember that the `/` path separator is commonly considered as standard (with Windows being the only, very annoying exception, no matter its "believed" diffusion). It's usually better to use the python PathLib or the Qt classes (such as QDir). Besides, using standard slashes doesn't require any escape, which is also a major point.

Comment: @musicamante
completely agree with your point. I have edited the answer.